# Wait until download is complete before starting other tasks

Tags: vb.net, user-interface

I am trying to download a file, and then run some adb commands. However when downloading, i could not get it to update the progress bar using

```
downloadFile(url,filename)` command.
```

A bit of searching it said that the command was blocking the UI thread, so i decided to use `Task.Run()` (a solution to my previous post to run ADB Commands when it blocked the UIThread).

This made no difference. Another solution that i found is to use

```
downloadFileAsync(url, filename)
```

The progress bar is updating!

*But, the ADB commands are running before the file is downloaded!* They are declared after, but they are still being run before the file is downloaded, which I don't want.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub btnFlashRecovery_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFlashRecovery.Click
                    'Insert ommited Code here (removed to simplify question) 
                    'id is variable obtained from a previous code that was ommited here        
                    Dim fileName As String = "downloads/twrp-" & id & ".img"
                    DownloadFile(url, fileName)

                    'run the right commands

                    LabelToOutput = txtBoxRecovery
                    Dim commands(3, 3) As String
                    commands = {{"adb", "reboot bootloader", "Rebooting to bootloader"},
                                            {"fastboot", "flash recovery" & "downloads/twrp-3.1.1-0.img", "Flashing recovery: (make sure device is plugged, otherwise it will not output anything)"},
                                            {"fastboot", "reboot", "Rebooting device"}

                                        }
                    'Task to run after
                    Task.Run(Sub() runComands(commands))


End Sub

Private Sub UpdateProgressBar(ByVal a As Integer)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim args() As String = {a}
        Me.Invoke(New Action(Of String)(AddressOf UpdateProgressBar), args)
        Return
    End If
    ProgressBar1.Value = CInt(a)

End Sub

Public Sub DownloadFile(urlAddress As String, location As String)
    Using webClient = New WebClient()
        AddHandler webClient.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf Completed
        AddHandler webClient.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf ProgressChanged



        Try
            ' Start downloading the file

            webClient.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(urlAddress), location)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Using

End Sub

' The event that will fire whenever the progress of the WebClient is changed
Private Sub ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs)

    'Console.WriteLine(e.ProgressPercentage)
    ' Update the progressbar percentage only when the value is not the same.
    UpdateProgressBar(e.ProgressPercentage)



End Sub

' The event that will trigger when the WebClient is completed
Private Sub Completed(sender As Object, e As AsyncCompletedEventArgs)


    If e.Cancelled = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("Download has been canceled.")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Download completed!")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You have already subscribed to the `DownloadFileCompleted` event, why not put your code in there?

Comment: @VisualVincent I did not add it there because i need to reuse the `DownloadFile` Function with other buttons, and adding it there would remove the modularity.

Comment: Why not adding a timer with an interval of `1`, and the code that you want to run after the download is complete in a separated sub, and in the timer check if the file `Dim fileName As String = "downloads/twrp-" & id & ".img"` is exist, when the file is exist call the separated sub.

Comment: @MousaAlfhaily forgot to add that i tried that to set a variable to to check if the task is finished, and go to sleep, but it blocked the whole thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
'Need Async keyword with the method
Private Async Sub btnFlashRecovery_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFlashRecovery.Click
    'Insert ommited Code here (removed to simplify question) 

    'id is variable obtained from a previous code that was ommited here        
     Dim fileName As String = "downloads/twrp-" & id & ".img"
    'You need to AWAIT the result of the task
     Await Task.Run(Sub() DownloadFile(url, fileName))

    'run the right commands
    LabelToOutput = txtBoxRecovery
    Dim commands(3, 3) As String
    commands = { {"adb", "reboot bootloader", "Rebooting to bootloader"},
                 {"fastboot", "flash recovery" & "downloads/twrp-3.1.1-0.img", "Flashing recovery: (make sure device is plugged, otherwise it will not output anything)"},
                 {"fastboot", "reboot", "Rebooting device"}
               }
    'Task to run after
    'Await here, too, to allow the UI to remain responsive
    Await Task.Run(Sub() runComands(commands))
End Sub
```

Comment: What about awaiting `DownloadFileTaskAsync`?

Comment: @Nkosi  The purpose of the answer was to demonstrate "await" as the missing piece. I don't think DownloadFileTaskAsync is strictly necessary for that, and so including it could mislead that it's required. But yes, it's probably the better choice.

Comment: @Nkosi neither of the answer work. It still moves on to run the commands

Comment: @FabioRameiro It shouldn't. The purpose of `Await` is to setup a _continuation_, such that execution of the method is effectively paused until the Awaited task is completed.

Comment: @Joel It does continue for some reason. I have added all 2 `await` and `async`

Comment: You may need to use the DownloadFileAsync option and update it to to return a Task

Comment: Hmm... maybe just `Task.Run( ... ).Wait()` will do what you need.

Comment: @Joel  `Task.Run( ... ).Wait()` does nothing

Comment: @Nkosi and Joel I was able to do it!. You were right about the `await` missing!. What you need to do was change `Dim r = Await DownloadFileAsync(nod.InnerText, fileName)` and inside the function `DownloadFile`, make it `async` and a function that returns something (integer in my case), and change the line to `Await webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(New Uri(urlAddress), location)`.

Comment: @FabioRameiro yes that was what I was suggesting with the use of `DownloadFileTaskAsync`

Comment: @Nkoshi sorry my bad! Noob at work. I misread your comment. the `dim r` bit is not necessary at all now that i look back. However i am pretty sure that i did put `await dowload.Download FileTaskAsync` and changed it into async and a function, but it did not work. anyways it works fine! Thank you to all that helped